# Golang short variable declarations show err unresolved

Tags: go

I am a new hand come from `Java` to `Go`

Look at my codes

```
package utils

import "os"

type FileController struct{
    file *os.File
}

func (c *FileController)OpenFile(path string)error{
    c.file, err := os.OpenFile(path,os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR,0755)

    //return some value these
}
```

I want to open a file but this not works

Goland tell me `Unresolved reference 'err'`

If I init err first, I write follow codes

```
var err error
c.file, err = os.OpenFile(path,os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR,0755)
```

`Goland` also tell me `Unused variable 'err'`

But if I use

```
f, err := os.OpenFile(path,os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR,0755)
c.file = f
_ = err
```

I works

I think `:=` will works at least have a un-declaration variable in left

c.file already been inited, err a new variable.

Should I must use second way?

I feel that the first way is not elegant.

---

**Update-1**

When I use @GreatDharmatma method.

Golang tell me `Unresolved variable err`

[image]

---

**Update-2**

It's works, I not notice @GreatDharmatma return `(err error)`

It's my fault.

**This's a Summary:**

1. `:=` used only if all of left variable not declare before
2. if `a variable` have been declared before(like c.file).

   We need pre-declare `err` before `os.OpenFile(path,os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR,0755)`

   `var err error`
3. Another way to solve this problem is use `named return value` as `@GreatDharmatma` said.

From `Golang docs`

[Docs-Named-variable](https://tour.golang.org/basics/7)

> Go's return values may be named. If so, they are treated as variables defined at the top of the function.

Thank all of you!
Have a nice day!

---

**Update-3 After two days**

From @LukeJoshuaPark comment.

> Using a short variable declaration requires both variables to not be declared first" - Not true. To use a short variable declaration, at least one must not be declared

What `LukeJoshuaPark` is right, I ask a same in `golang-nuts`

*My reply*

```
For all typed object such as `type *** struct`, `type *** func()`, `type **** int`, their field cannot be redeclare? and cannot be used at left side of `:=`?
```

*heat-heart firend said*

> That is correct. A member field cannot be on the left side of :=
>
> This is the from the spec:
>
> It is shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types:
>
> "var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .
>
> So,
>
> x, y:=values
>
> is identical to
>
> var x, y = values
>
> Applying this rule to your example, it becomes:
>
> var c.file, err=os.OpenFile...
>
> which is not valid.

### *Thanks.Question Over*

Comment: `:=` is strictly used to declare variables.  If you need to assign to an existing variable (like `c.file`) you need to use `=`.

Comment: And Go requires you to read every variable that is written to.  If you don't plan on reading `err`, replace it with `_` in your assignment.

Comment: Correct but using `=` would still cause an error because err would not be declared first to be assigned. See my answer.

Comment: @ctt he needs the error as he is planning to return it from the function.

Comment: If s/he needs to return it, then he needs to do his two-l-value assignment with `=` and declare `err` ahead of time.  You've provided one possible option.  Another is to use a `var` statement to declare `err` prior to the dual-value assignment.

Comment: You followed my answer partially. You updated the assignment operator but not the named return type. You need to use (err error) as return type and not just error. See the image in my answer.

Comment: @toffee consider reading the comments and answer very carefully.  They end up explaining precisely the errors you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is because you are using :=

Using a short variable declaration requires both variables to not be declared first. In your case c.file is declared and err is not. Hence the error. Try the following snippet instead.

```
func (c *FileController)OpenFile(path string)(err error){
    c.file, err = os.OpenFile(path,os.O_CREATE | os.O_RDWR,0755)

    //return some value these
}
```

This should work just fine

[image]

Comment: In this case both c.file and err are declared before hand and you can use assignment without facing a problem.

Comment: Where err is declared? It not works, `Goland` tell me `Unresolved reference `err``, look at my updated question

Comment: err is a named return here. Take a look at your function and my function definition very carefully `func (c *FileController)OpenFile(path string)error` and `func (c *FileController)OpenFile(path string)(err error)`

Comment: Yes, It works now, if I return `(err error)`,  Did it mean "I want to return err, so please help me declare err first"? 

I notice you not declare err first.
c.file exists, but err not.

Comment: I solve by myself about `named return values`, Thank you!

From `Go doc`
`Go's return values may be named. If so, they are treated as variables defined at the top of the function.`

Comment: *"Using a short variable declaration requires both variables to not be declared first"* - Not true.  To use a short variable declaration, at least *one* must not be declared.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I am not sure, `err` is not be declared, why `c.file, err :=**************` is not working? Goland said : `Unresolved reference 'err'`

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark , Hi, I am really want to know what you said about `" To use a short variable declaration, at least one must not be declared."`

In my case, c.file is declared, err is a new variable, But why `Goland IDE` tell me `unresolved reference err`

if you don't have time, you can give me some url or keywords, I will do by myself, Thankyou!